# Strange output for luajit ffi function returning string

Tags: c++, string, c++11, lua, luajit

I have a function like the following returning a c-string from an another function returning a std::string.

```
const char* GetFilePath(const char* aFilename)
{
    return FileSystem->GetFilePath(aFilename).c_str();
}
```

If I call this function from lua I only get garbage. If I modify the function to return for example a "Test" it works.

I think it is because the returned std::string's destructor will be called and therefore delets the string making the c-string invalid.

My question is how can I prevent this? How can I get this working?

UPDATE:
I expose this function to Lua with the following.

```
local ffi = require('ffi')
ffi.cdef[[
const char* GetFilePath(const char* aFilename)
]]

x = ffi.string(GetFilePath("Script.lua"))
io.write(x)
```

This code just prints some random garbage. But if I modify the C-Wrapper function to just to return a C-Style string I get the desired output.

Update 2:
For example if I do something like the following:

```
const char* GetFilePath(const char* aFilename)
{
    return aFilename;
}
```

It works as expected. Also when I expose some other functions returning an const char*.
BUT if I do the following:

```
const char* GetFilePath(const char* aFilename)
{
    return std::string(aFilename).c_str();
}
```

I get random garbage. My original C++-Function returns an std::string.

Comment: In your update2, this code `return std::string(aFilename).c_str();` is never correct. That will always give undefined behavior, no matter about lua bindings or anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on using the luajit FFI for this instead of using the C api, you are going to have to write some more complicated C++.

The issue is that, any function that returns `const char *` in C++, cannot be generated by calling `c_str()` on a local or temporary `std::string` because it will become invalid before lua gets a chance to use it.

The simplest trick to get around this is to use a `static` local variable, which won't be destroyed right after the function returns.

```
const char* GetFilePath(const char* aFilename)
{
    static std::string long_lived;
    long_lived = FileSystem->GetFilePath(aFilename);
    return long_lived.c_str();
}
```

There's some extra overhead here -- the `long_lived` string will be allocated until `GetFilePath` is called again, or your program ends. But these strings are small, so this overhead doesn't matter much.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This fixes my problem. I may try to redesign my code or use the standard lua c api again.